# How to Extend the Plane and make it snap it to the Landing?

Tags: modeling

[image: Screenshot of plane and steps]

I want to extend the plane at the same angle and snap it to the landing

I am unable to extend the plane at the same angle and snap it to the upper landing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit mode
2. turn on Snap to Face
3. Select wanted Edge
4. Edge Slide (G-G)
5. Hold Alt to turn off clamping
6. Slide to intersecting plane

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad it helped.